# Optimization of nonlinear equations

Tags: r, optimization, statistics

I posted this question a couple weeks ago and didn't receive any replies that answered my question, so I'm trying again with hopefully cleaned up R code.

What I'm doing here is taking a naturally occurring gas isotope of C12 and C13 that is produced at a linear rate (P) at respective fractions (F12 and F13) that sum to 1. The two isotopic gases are then consumed at rates k12 for C13 and k13 for C13. I then want to solve for P and k12 using a minimization function.

The equations are:

Eqn 1: conc.12 = ((F12*P)/k12)-(((F12*P)/k12)-c12zero)exp(-k12(t-t0))

Eqn 2: conc.13 = ((F13*P)/k13)-(((F13*P)/k13)-c13zero)exp(-k13(t-t0))

Eqn 3: Error = sum(((conc.12-c12meas)/0.07)^2) +sum(((conc.13-c13meas)/0.07)^2)

conc.12 and conc.13 are the estimated concentrations of two isotopes at time t

c12meas and c13meas are the measured concentrations of two isotopes at time t

t0 is the initial time point

F12 and F13 are fractions that sum to 1

k12 and k13 are exponential decay coefficients for the two isotopes, with k13 = k12/1.06

P is a linear production rate of both 12CH4 and 13CH4

```
c12meas <- c(109.7000,118.9150,127.6693,135.9858,143.8865,151.3922,
   158.5226, 165.2964, 171.7316, 177.8450, 183.6528, 189.1701,
   194.4116, 199.3911, 204.1215, 208.6154, 212.8847, 216.9404,
   220.7934, 224.4537)

c13meas <- c(19.35660,18.74356,18.15943,17.60285,17.07253,16.56722,
   16.08575,15.62698,15.18986,14.77336,14.37650,13.99837,
   13.63807,13.29476,12.96765,12.65597,12.35899,12.07602,
   11.80639,11.54949)

t <- c(1:20)

isotopes<- function (x) {   #where x[1] = P, x[2] = k12
  t0<-t[1]
  c12zero=100
  c13zero=20
  k13=x[2]/1.06
  F12=0.98
  F13=1-F12
  ratio.12<- (F12*x[1])/x[2]
  exp.12<- exp(-x[2]*(t-t0))
  conc.12<-ratio.12 - ((ratio.12-c12zero)*exp.12)
  ratio.13<- (F13*x[1])/k13
  exp.13<- exp(-k13*(t-t0))
  conc.13<- ratio.13 - ((ratio.13-c13zero)*exp.13)
  error <- sum(((conc.12-c12meas)/0.07)^2)
    +sum(((conc.13-c13meas)/0.07)^2)
  results <- list(conc.12, conc.13, error)
  return(results)
}
```

The function itself works fine:

```
newdata <- isotopes(x= c(15, 0.05))  
newdata
```

Try the optimx function. You'll need to load the package.

```
x= c(15, 0.05)
optim.result <- optimx(x, isotopes, all.methods=T)
```

The following error message occurs:
*Error in optimx.check(par, optcfg$ufn, optcfg$ugr, optcfg$uhess, lower,  : 
Cannot evaluate function at initial parameters*

Comment: You shouldn't just open another copy of the same question. Editing the old question will bump it up to the top of the activity list and get it new attention.

Comment: You seem to have improved the formatting here - editing the old question to have those improvements will be a good excuse to bump it.

Comment: Also, I think the comments on your original question can be very helpful: the first comment states *"you need to crunch down your objective function so that it evaluates to a scalar"*. This can be verified at `?optimx` which describes the function "*A function to be minimized... **It should return a scalar result**.*" [emphasis mine]. When I run your definitions and then evaluate `isotopes(x= c(15, 0.05))`, I get a `list`, not a scalar. Your function should return *a single number* that can be minimized.

Comment: Perhaps you just need `return(error)` at then end, and skip making that results list.

Comment: Yes, the return function not being a scaler seemed to be the problem. I've gotten it to work now with your suggestion and a bit a change in syntax in the optimax statement. Thanks for your help.